# Maximization of a function with inequality constraint in R

Tags: r

I have 3 variables `b1`, `b2` and `b3`, which can have different value each time. I wrote the function `f`, and I would like to maximize `f` with the following constraint.

inequality constraint

b1, b2 >= 0 and b3 <= 1000

```
b1 = c(1, 2)
b2 = 3
b3 = c(1, 1)
theta = c(b1, b2, b3)
f = function(theta){
    sum(-exp(theta[1:length(b1)]^2
    + theta[(length(b1)+1):(length(b1)+length(b2))]^2)
    + theta[(length(b1)+length(b2)+1):length(theta)]^2)
}
```

Which packages can I use in R?

Comment: Have a look at here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/constrOptim.html

Comment: I dont have ui  : constraint matrix (k x p). Just I have ci.I dont know how to define ci .

Comment: You can't just have a ci without a ui.  That link is exactly what you want.

Comment: Could you define ui and ci for the above mentioned example?